My swiper autoplay isnt working, How to make it work
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react"
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay, Navigation, EffectFade } from "swiper"
import { Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap"
import "swiper/css"
import "swiper/css/effect-fade"
import "swiper/css/navigation"
import "swiper/css/pagination"
import { Button } from "@mui/material"

import { SliderData, Sports } from "./data"
import Spline from "@splinetool/react-spline"

SwiperCore.use([Autoplay, Navigation, EffectFade])

const DesktopSlider = () => {
  const mainSlideOptions = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    direction: "horizontal",
    loop: true,
    effect: "fade",
    navigation: {
      nextEl: "#main-slider-next",
      prevEl: "#main-slider-prev",
    },
    autoplay: {
      delay: 3000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
  }

  const formatSportsList = () => {
    if (Sports?.length === 0) return ""

    let formattedList = Sports.join(", ").replace(/, ([^,]*)$/, " and $1")

    const lastCommaIndex = formattedList.lastIndexOf(", ")
    if (lastCommaIndex !== -1) {
      formattedList =
        formattedList.substring(0, lastCommaIndex) +
        " and" +
        formattedList.substring(lastCommaIndex + 1)
    }

    return formattedList.split(" ").map(item => <span>{item}</span>)
  }

  return (
    <section className="main-slider overflow-hidden">
      <Container>`your text`
        <Swiper {...mainSlideOptions}>
          {SliderData.map(
            ({ bannerImage, subTitle, title, buttons, text }, index) => (
              <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                <div
                  className="image-layer"
                  style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bannerImage})` }}
                ></div>

                <div className="banner-slider">
                  <Row>
                    <Col className="text-center">
                      <h1 className="main-slider__title">{title}</h1>
                      <p className="main-slider__subtext">{subTitle}</p>
                      <div className="sports-list">{formatSportsList()}</div>
                      <div className="button-block">
                        {buttons.map((item) => (
                          <Link to="#contact-sec" key={item.label}>
                            <Button > {item.label} </Button>
                          </Link>
                        ))}
                      </div>

                      <div className="banner-slider-bottom-text">
                        <p className="text-center">{text}</p>
                      </div>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </div>
              </SwiperSlide>
            )
          )}
        </Swiper>
      </Container>
    </section>
  )
}

export default DesktopSlider

I did import Autoplay and called it with Swipercore.use, it didnt work.
I have added disableOnInteraction to find if anything is wrong with it.
I tried many ways to make it work but failed miserably, my swiper version is 11.1.1
can anyone help me with this!
It was working with 8.2.3, but when I upgraded swiper it stopped working
thanks in advance

https://swiperjs.com/demos#autoplay
